# c++0x std::function as a method argument

Tags: c++, function, bind, c++11

I'm attempting to pass an `std::function` via a method like so:

```
class dispatch
{
  public:
     deliver( std::function<void ( void )> task );
};
```

This works as expected. However i wish to pass arguments to some of the methods supplied as the task but would prefer not to have to create overloads for all the different `function< ... >` forms.

for example is it at all possible just to create a method like follows

```
deliver( std::function& task );
```

and just invoke with

```
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method, X ) );
```

or

```
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method, X, arg1, arg2 ) );
```

etc...

Thanks for everyone's input. It would appear my real fault is with calls to `dispatch->deliver` with the additional argument also being a bind call.

```
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method1, X1, bind( &Object::method1, X2 ) );
```

> error: /usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1539:13: error: no matching function for call to '__mu_expand'
> return  __mu_expand(__ti, __uj, __indices());

Comment: Missing `;` after class declaration. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::function<void(void)>` is already polymorphic, that's the whole point of it. So those two last snippets will work (as long as the functor `bind` returns can be called with no arguments, and returns nothing, of course), without changing what you already have.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible as long as you use bind to generate compatible function objects:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

typedef boost::function<void(void)> fun_t;
typedef std::list<fun_t> funs_t;

void foo()
    { std::cout <<"\n"; }
void bar(int p)
    { std::cout<<"("<<p<<")\n"; }
void goo(std::string const& p)
    { std::cout<<"("<<p<<")\n"; }

void caller(fun_t f)
    { f(); }

int main()
{
    funs_t f;
    f.push_front(boost::bind(foo));
    f.push_front(boost::bind(bar, int(17)));
    f.push_front(boost::bind(goo, "I am goo"));

    for (funs_t::iterator it = f.begin(); it != f.end(); ++it)
    {
        caller(*it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Note, I use Boost.Function and Boost.Bind, but there should be no difference to use of std::bind and std::function.)

Comment: Should I prefer to pass `fun_t` by value or reference?

Comment: @hkBattousai It depends. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/8711486/151641 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18366273/151641

Answer (score 2):

```
class dispatch
{
  public:
     template <typename ... Params>
     deliver( std::function<void (Params && p...)> task, Params && p )
     {
         task(std::forward(p)...);
     }
};
```

I haven't compiled this (corrections welcome!), but the idea should work.

```
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method, X ) );
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method, X, arg1, arg2 ) ); // OR!
dispatch->deliver( bind( &Object::method, X ), arg1, arg2 );
```

The one thing I'm unclear about is how this behaves if `Object::method` has defaulted params instead of overloads.

Comment: +1: One nitpick, It might be more efficient to pass the std::function as const reference.

Comment: @DirkM You are right, but since the OP didn't do it, I chose not to as well.  He could be doing something in that deliver method that isn't involved with "delivery". I hope not though.