# When constructing a derived class which defines a base class member of some large type, how should I pass the value?

Tags: c++, inheritance, move-semantics

Suppose I have 3 classes: `Base`, `Derived` and `Chunky`. `Derived` is derived from `Base`, and `Base` has a member of type `Chunky` (`Chunky` is large, and I don't want to copy it unless I have to).

Here is `Base`, assume that we *cannot* change it in any way (no, we can't create a constructor for it):

```
class Base
{
public:
  Chunky monkey;
}
```

`Derived` looks something like this:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  // option 1
  Derived(Chunky const& monkey)
  {
    this->monkey = monkey;
  }

  // option 2
  Derived(Chunky monkey)
  {
    // does this do anything useful, or am I wasting my time by calling std::move?
    this->monkey = std::move(monkey);
  }
}
```

I like option 2 better because the intent is clearer and I don't have to create a reference value, but do we still have the benefit of `std::move` when `monkey` can't be initialised in constructor initializer list? How would *you* solve this problem (again assuming `Base` can't change)?

In case anyone wants to know, *monkey* in this case is an std::function, and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711391/should-i-copy-an-stdfunction-or-can-i-always-take-a-reference-to-it) didn't really answer my question.

Comment: Can monkey be a pointer (use new, delete etc.) you can pass around the and even make NULL if you don't need it?

Comment: @Atle no, `Chunky` is actually of type `std::function` in my case. Besides, I'm not allowed to modify `Base` so it has to be a value.

Comment: std::function is not that large, and can be copied. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @BЈовић how big is it? I have no idea...

Comment: The assignment in option 1 will copy the object, I guess.

Comment: 32 bytes on my system (64bit ubuntu)

Comment: @BЈовић: Size of `std::vector` is also small, but that does not mean that copying is cheap.

Comment: @JurajBlaho No, it doesn't, since it depends on the particular implementation. If the implementation do a shallow copy - it is going to be very cheap. Now copying `std::function` should not be expensive, unless it is implemented in a very crappy way

Comment: @BЈовић: Shallow copy may not be enough. Consider mutable capture by value: http://ideone.com/r3HjZx

Comment: @JurajBlaho Never mind that vector thing. Copying std::function is cheap.

Comment: @BЈовић: Yes it may be fast, but it does depend on the actual function stored. With expensive to copy captured variables the difference between move and copy is big: http://ideone.com/2ZiBFq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is still the benefit of move in the second case, even if the move is not in the member initializer list. But be aware that in this case move assignment is used instead of move construction, so the `Chunky` type needs to support that. As `Chunky` is `std::function` it is OK.

The second option seems preferable as it may avoid copy compared to the first option. In the better case it needs just two moves, but in the worse case a copy followed by a move is performed. The first option always needs a single copy.