# How to set std::function in class

Tags: c++, std

I have a class

```
class MyClass
{
   typedef std::function<void(const std::string &str> SomeFunc;
   SomeFunc Func;
}
```

I want to have set for this function. I did one

```
void MyClass::SetFunc(SomeFunc Func1)
{
    Func = Func1;
}
```

I need in my class funtion as member and I want to use std::function, because it's alowes to use lambda. If the lambda is complicated, I will need move of function. If lambda is simply, a copy will be nice. And i don't know how to do it

Comment: moving a pointer *is*  a copy. The question is rather unclear. Do you actually want `SoemFunc Func;` as member?

Comment: If you don't want to *move*, why are you calling `move`?  What's wrong with `Func = Func1;`?

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing function pointers and `std::function`. Just use `SomeFunc` wherever you currently use `SomeFunc*` and it should be much easier.

Comment: after the edit I dont see the issue with the code. "How I can do move? I need 2 set: copy and move." do you mean you need to overloads of `SetFunc`, one that copies and one that moves? Did you try to write a second overload? I wouldnt bother too much about moving vs copying a `std::function` though

Comment: Yes, I mean this question @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: if you post a [mcve] including the real class definition and a lambda for which you need to move the question would be much easier to answer

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer
[Should I copy an std::function or can I always take a reference to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711391/should-i-copy-an-stdfunction-or-can-i-always-take-a-reference-to-it)

```
void MyClass::SetFunc(const SomeFunc &Func1)
{
    Func= Func;
}

void MyClass::SetFunc(SomeFunc &&Func1)
{
    Func= std::move(Func);
}
```