# Should I pass an std::function by const-reference?

Tags: c++, function, reference, std-function

Let's say I have a function which takes an `std::function`:

```
void callFunction(std::function<void()> x)
{
    x();
}
```

Should I pass `x` by const-reference instead?:

```
void callFunction(const std::function<void()>& x)
{
    x();
}
```

Does the answer to this question change depending on what the function does with it? For example, if it is a member function or constructor which stores or initializes the `std::function` into a data member.

Comment: Probably not. I don't know for sure, but I would expect `sizeof(std::function)` to be no more than `2 * sizeof(size_t)`, which is the least size that you'd ever consider for a const reference.

Comment: @Mats: I don't think the size of the `std::function` wrapper is as important as the complexity of copying it.  If deep copies are involved, it could be far more expensive than `sizeof` suggests.

Comment: Should you `move` the function in?

Comment: `operator()()` is `const` so a const reference should work. But I've never used std::function.

Comment: @Yakk I just pass a lambda directly to the function.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But what is there to copy? `std::function` itself doesn't hold a copy of a class or anything like that, right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson If a lambda is involved, yes `function` does hold a copy of the anonymous closure class. And depending on the captured variables, copying the lambda could be quite expensive.

Comment: @syam All right, I will just pass it by const-reference then.

Comment: @SvenAdbring Not necessarily. ;) Look at my answer to get a good use case of passing by value, it may help you (I hope) choosing the right one. In C++11 passing by value does not always involve copying!

Comment: @syam Ooh, didn't think of std::move :) That seems to work perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 103):

If you want performance, pass by value if you are storing it.

Suppose you have a function called "run this in the UI thread".

```
std::future<void> run_in_ui_thread( std::function<void()> )
```

which runs some code in the "ui" thread, then signals the `future` when done.  (Useful in UI frameworks where the UI thread is where you are supposed to mess with UI elements)

We have two signatures we are considering:

```
std::future<void> run_in_ui_thread( std::function<void()> ) // (A)
std::future<void> run_in_ui_thread( std::function<void()> const& ) // (B)
```

Now, we are likely to use these as follows:

```
run_in_ui_thread( [=]{
  // code goes here
} ).wait();
```

which will create an anonymous closure (a lambda), construct a `std::function` out of it, pass it to the `run_in_ui_thread` function, then wait for it to finish running in the main thread.

In case (A), the `std::function` is directly constructed from our lambda, which is then used within the `run_in_ui_thread`.  The lambda is `move`d into the `std::function`, so any movable state is efficiently carried into it.

In the second case, a temporary `std::function` is created, the lambda is `move`d into it, then that temporary `std::function` is used by reference within the `run_in_ui_thread`.

So far, so good -- the two of them perform identically.  Except the `run_in_ui_thread` is going to make a copy of its function argument to send to the ui thread to execute! (it will return before it is done with it, so it cannot just use a reference to it).  For case (A), we simply `move` the `std::function` into its long-term storage.  In case (B), we are forced to copy the `std::function`.

That store makes passing by value more optimal.  If there is any possibility you are storing a copy of the `std::function`, pass by value.  Otherwise, either way is roughly equivalent: the only downside to by-value is if you are taking the same bulky `std::function` and having one sub method after another use it.  Barring that, a `move` will be as efficient as a `const&`.

Now, there are some other differences between the two that mostly kick in if we have persistent state within the `std::function`.

Assume that the `std::function` stores some object with a `operator() const`, but it also has some `mutable` data members which it modifies (how rude!).

In the `std::function<> const&` case, the `mutable` data members modified will propagate out of the function call.  In the `std::function<>` case, they won't.

This is a relatively strange corner case.

You want to treat `std::function` like you would any other possibly heavy-weight, cheaply movable type.  Moving is cheap, copying can be expensive.

Comment: The semantic advantage of "pass by value if you are storing it", as you say, is that by contract the function can't keep the address of the argument passed.  But is it really true that "Barring that, a move will be as efficient as a const&"? I always see the cost of a copy operation plus the cost of the move operation. With passing by `const&` I only see the cost of the copy operation.

Comment: @ceztko In both (A) and (B) cases, the temporary `std::function` is created from the lambda.  In (A), the temporary is elided into the argument to `run_in_ui_thread`.  In (B) a reference to said temporary is passed to `run_in_ui_thread`.  So long as your `std::function`s are created from lambdas as temporaries, that clause holds.  The previous paragraph deals with the case where the `std::function` persists.  If we *are not* storing, just creating from a lambda, `function const&` and `function` have the exact same overhead.

Comment: Ah, I see! This of course depends of what happens outside of `run_in_ui_thread()`. Is there just a signature to say "Pass by reference, but I won't store the address"?

Comment: @ceztko No, there is not.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont if would be more complete to cover another option to pass by rvalue ref: `std::future<void> run_in_ui_thread( std::function<void()>&& )`

Comment: Would you please introduce some sources or books to get to know how std::function is working behind the scenes. I still don't get your explanations. Thanks

Comment: @passionateProgrammer Better late than never.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented

Answer (score 40):

If you're worried about performance, and you aren't defining a virtual member function, then you most likely should not be using `std::function` at all.

Making the functor type a template parameter permits greater optimization than `std::function`, including inlining the functor logic.  The effect of these optimizations is likely to greatly outweigh the copy-vs-indirection concerns about how to pass `std::function`.

Faster:

```
template<typename Functor>
void callFunction(Functor&& x)
{
    x();
}
```

Comment: I'm not worried at all about performance actually. I just thought using const-references where they should be used is common practice (strings and vectors come to mind).

Comment: @Ben: I think the most modern hippie-friendly way of implementing this is to use `std::forward<Functor>(x)();`, to preserve the value category of the functor, since it's a "universal" reference. Not going to make a difference in 99% of the cases, though.

Comment: Nice one, I wasn't aware that this would admit Lambda functions.

Comment: @Ben Voigt so for your case, would I call the function with a move? `callFunction(std::move(myFunctor));`

Comment: @arias_JC: If the parameter is a lambda, it's already an rvalue.  If you have a lvalue, you can either use `std::move` if you will no longer need it in any other way, or pass directly if you don't want to move out of the existing object.  Reference-collapsing rules ensure that `callFunction<T&>()` has a parameter of type `T&`, not `T&&`.

Comment: Nice! @BenVoigt would you mind updating this to (1) incorporate the suggestion from @GManNickG, and (2) expand for the case of passing arguments to `x`.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain: I've chosen not to make that change because it's only valid for the simplest case, when the function is called only once.  My answer is to the question of "how should I pass a function object?" and not limited to a function that does nothing besides unconditionally invoke that functor exactly once.

Comment: @GManNickG We can go further and use `std::invoke(std::forward<Functor>(x))` now

Comment: You can even use C++20 constraints to make sure `Functor` is of the right type.

Comment: @MAChitgarha: Yes, that's a good way to move the error to the call-site, where the correction needs to be made, instead of inside the library code.  Wasn't a very good option for that sort of thing back when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 35):

As usual in C++11, passing by value/reference/const-reference depends on what you do with your argument. `std::function` is no different.

**Passing by value** allows you to move the argument into a variable (typically a member variable of a class):

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Object o) : m_o(std::move(o)) {}

    Object m_o;
};
```

When you know your function will move its argument, this is the best solution, this way your users can control how they call your function:

```
Foo f1{Object()};               // move the temporary, followed by a move in the constructor
Foo f2{some_object};            // copy the object, followed by a move in the constructor
Foo f3{std::move(some_object)}; // move the object, followed by a move in the constructor
```

I believe you already know the semantics of (non)const-references so I won't belabor the point. If you need me to add more explanations about this, just ask and I'll update.