# How does std::function store the context of a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, std-function

Given a lambda function with a captured variable, like

```
[&x] (int y) { x += y; }
```

where is the context (here a reference to some variable `int x` defined anywhere within the lexical context) stored when I pass this lambda to a variable of type `std::function<void(int)>`?

I know dynamic size storages like `std::vector` or `std::string`, but they all store a fixed type of values (once the template parameters are known of course). But in the case of lambdas, such a storage should be able to store *any* type of values, known at compile time of the client code which assigns a lambda to a `std::function`, but not known when passing the function around.

I mean, when we fix the concrete type of `std::function`, we fix the *function signature*, but not the types of the captured variables / references. There got to be some dynamic size *and* dynamic type storage behind the scene. Clearly, this can't be for example a `std::tuple` because that would require the types to be known when instancing the `std::function` but they are not. So I wonder how it's implemented (e.g. in g++, but there might be a compiler-independent answer to this question).

Comment: probably type erasure.

Comment: Lambda is really a struct that defines `operator()()` and `function` stores it like every other callable object.

Comment: `std::function` deals with different-sized objects all the time (function pointers, bound pointers to members, functors, lambdas); as often happens with type erasure classes, in line of principle it can use dynamic allocation and polymorphism mixed with some template magic to do its job (although I wouldn't be surprised if it had some "small object optimization" in place).

Comment: Let me answer that with another question: how does `std::function` store the members of a function object? (Lambdas are not special)

Comment: OK, the lambda was an example, of course the same problem arises for any functor.

Comment: @aaronman: You should provide a link to the question, not a particular answer. Specially considering that the answer you link is not correct: *I doubt that `std::function` needs to allocate heap space*. Otherwise, good call on the duplicate question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that was an accident being a product of how I remembered I'd seen the answer somewhere, I'll fix it

Comment: Yup, that question is pretty much the same. Voting my own question to close ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented, here is the link to the actual question

Comment: @aaronman: You should correct your answer to that other question, there is no point in leaving a knowingly wrong answer stay there