# Do C++ compilers perform compile-time optimizations on lambda closures?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, lambda, llvm-clang

Suppose we have the following (nonsensical) code:

```
const int a = 0;
int c = 0;
for(int b = 0; b < 10000000; b++)
{
    if(a) c++;
    c += 7;
}
```

Variable 'a' equals zero, so the compiler can deduce on compile time, that the instruction 'if(a) c++;' will never be executed and will optimize it away.

My question: **Does the same happen with lambda closures?**

Check out another piece of code:

```
const int a = 0;
function<int()> lambda = [a]()
{
    int c = 0;
    for(int b = 0; b < 10000000; b++)
    {
        if(a) c++;
        c += 7;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Will the compiler know that 'a' is 0 and will it optimize the lambda?

Even more sophisticated example:

```
function<int()> generate_lambda(const int a)
{
    return [a]()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < 10000000; b++)
        {
            if(a) c++;
            c += 7;
        }
        return c;
    };
}

function<int()> a_is_zero = generate_lambda(0);
function<int()> a_is_one = generate_lambda(1);
```

Will the compiler be smart enough to optimize the first lambda when it knows that 'a' is 0 at generation time?

Does gcc or llvm have this kind of optimizations?

I'm asking because I wonder if I should make such optimizations manually when I know that certain assumptions are satisfied on lambda generation time or the compiler will do that for me.

Comment: Do you know of [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) ? It will pretty much answer all of your questions, and more :) -- Also, `std::function` will probably not be optimized out, as its type-erasing purpose directly clashes with inlining.

Comment: @Quentin Seeing through type erasure is a hot topic for compilers, and they are getting not so bad at it.

Comment: I stopped compiling code into DLLS because with static libraries the compiler most times optimize aways virtual calls, this happens even with GCC but I fear it's off topic for such question ^^

Comment: Since we have a [memory allocation going on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18453145/1708801) the answer to [Is the compiler allowed to optimize out heap memory allocations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31873616/1708801) may help to define the limits around optimization of this case.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It doesn't need to have memory allocation, several libraries implement an optimization to store small functors without allocating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the assembly generated by gcc5.2 -O2 shows that the optimization does not happen when using `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    const int a = 0;    
    std::function<int()> lambda = [a]()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < 10000000; b++)
        {
            if(a) c++;
            c += 7;
        }
        return c;
    };

    return lambda();
}
```

compiles to some boilerplate and

```
    movl    (%rdi), %ecx
    movl    $10000000, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    cmpl    $1, %ecx
    sbbl    $-1, %eax
    addl    $7, %eax
    subl    $1, %edx
    jne .L3
    rep; ret
```

which is the loop you wanted to see optimized away. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f20e18328468b2)) But if you actually use a lambda (and not an `std::function`), the optimization does happen:

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 0;    
    auto lambda = [a]()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < 10000000; b++)
        {
            if(a) c++;
            c += 7;
        }
        return c;
    };

    return lambda();
}
```

compiles to

```
movl    $70000000, %eax
ret
```

i.e. the loop was removed completely. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f227f59fcd0526c7))

Afaik, you can expect a lambda to have zero overhead, but `std::function` is different and comes with a cost (at least at the current state of the optimizers, although people apparently work on this), even if the code "inside the `std::function`" would have been optimized. (Take that with a grain of salt and try if in doubt, since this will probably vary between compilers and versions. `std::function`s overhead can certainly be optimized away.)

As @MarcGlisse correctly pointed out, clang3.6 performs the desired optimization (equivalent to the second case above) even with `std::function`. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02e54e23f2eb26ce))

Bonus edit, thanks to @MarkGlisse again: If the function that contains the `std::function` is *not* called `main`, the optimization happening with gcc5.2 is somewhere between gcc+main and clang, i.e. the function gets reduced to `return 70000000;` plus some extra code. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1648e9681fc3338))

Bonus edit 2, this time mine: If you use -O3, gcc will, <s>(for some reason)</s> as explained in [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300556/3002139), optimize the `std::function` to

```
cmpl    $1, (%rdi)
sbbl    %eax, %eax
andl    $-10000000, %eax
addl    $80000000, %eax
ret
```

and keep the rest as in the `not_main` case. So I guess at the bottom of the line, one will just have to measure when using `std::function`.

Comment: Yes, std::function is a pain to optimize. There has already been some progress (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59948).

Comment: Note that clang optimizes even the case with std::function.

Comment: In a funny way, if you rename `main` to `not_main` (so the function is not marked as cold, which disables some optimizations), gcc manages to understand that `return 70000000;` but it keeps some useless code before that...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ha, this is a funny observation, I never ran into this behavior. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: Side note: I still think std::function() should not exist at all and the whole closure thing should be part of the language, not of some library. This would open the door for all sorts of clever things for compiler writers. Splitting new language features between language and library also happens on other occasions and I never really like it. Just saying ;)

Comment: To have an explanation of the `O3` optimization take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32300556/1938163

Comment: @bitticker `std::function` *is* part of the language: compilers are not required to implement it as C++ code at all.  Most do, because it is easier to get right.  Honestly the hard part is the fact you can get the underlying object back out of the `std::function`, so optimization has to audit for that possibility before doing things like "discard everything".

Answer (score 3):

Both gcc at `-O3` and MSVC2015 Release won't optimize it away with this simple code and the lambda would actually be **called**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;    
    std::function<int()> lambda = [a]()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            if(a) c++;
            c += 7;
        }
        return c;
    };

    std::cout << lambda();

    return 0;
}
```

At `-O3` this is what gcc generates for the lambda (code from [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/))

```
lambda:
    cmp DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    sbb eax, eax
    and eax, -10
    add eax, 80
    ret
```

This is a contrived and optimized way to express the following:

- If `a` was a 0, the first comparison would set the carry flag `CR`. `eax` would actually be set to 32 1 values, `and`'ed with -10 (and that would yield -10 in eax) and then added 80 -> result is 70.
- If `a` was something different from 0, the first comparison would **not** set the carry flag `CR`, `eax` would be set to zero, the `and` would have no effect and it would be added 80 -> result is 80.

It has to be noted (thanks Marc Glisse) that if the function is marked as *cold* (i.e. unlikely to be called) gcc performs the right thing and optimizes the call away.

MSVC generates more verbose code but the comparison isn't skipped.

Clang is the only one which gets it right: the lambda hasn't its code optimized more than gcc did but it is **not called**

```
mov edi, std::cout
mov esi, 70
call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

Morale: Clang seems to get it right but the optimization challenge is still open.