# Is there a way to convert void (*)(uint32_t, void (*)(uint32_t)) to std::function<void(uint32_t, std::function<void(uint32_t)>)>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to build a C++ library which is usable from C as well.
This is the header file I want to be able to compile in C:

```cpp
typedef void (*log_function_t)(const char *);
typedef void (*delay_function_callback_t)(uint32_t);
typedef void (*delay_function_t)(uint32_t, delay_function_callback_t);

extern "C" void core_init(log_function_t logFunction, delay_function_t delayFunction);
```

However, since I'm writing the library in C++, it would be nice to work with std::function objects instead of function pointers, so I'd like to call functions like this:

```cpp
using LogFunction = std::function<void(const char*)>;
using DelayFunctionCallback = std::function<void(uint32_t)>;
using DelayFunction = std::function<void(uint32_t, DelayFunctionCallback)>;

void setLogFunction(const LogFunction& logFunction);
void setDelayFunction(const DelayFunction& delayFunction);
```

Calling the `setLogFunction` works just fine, but when I try to call `setDelayFunction`it doesn't work.

```cpp
void core_init(log_function_t logFunction, delay_function_t delayFunction)
{
    Utility::getInstance().setLogFunction(logFunction);
    Utility::getInstance().setDelayFunction(delayFunction);
}
```

It says: `Reference to type 'const DelayFunction' (aka 'const function<void (unsigned int, function<void (unsigned int)>)>') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'delay_function_t' (aka 'void(*)(unsigned int, void (*)(unsigned int))')`

Obviously I understand why it doesn't work, but I have a feeling that it should be possible to solve and I'm just not experienced enough to solve it.

Comment: For the sake of readability, can you please change your inline function-pointer definitions to `typedefs`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment, let me do that

Comment: Not the answer, but the C callback functions should have an additional `void *userdata` parameter, or something similar.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, I will build that once I got something that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking seem to be passing a function pointer from C to C++ where the function takes a `std::function` as argument. I'm afraid this is not possible just as C can't pass a function pointer that takes a `std::vector` as argument.

When calling `Utility::getInstance().setDelayFunction(delayFunction)`, the ctor of a specialized `std::function` (i.e. `DelayFunction`) is matched to construct from a function pointer. However, the match fails because the ctor (of `DelayFunction`) accepts as its 2nd argument a specialized `std::function` (i.e. `DelayFunctionCallback`) , rather than a function pointer (i.e. `delay_function_callback_t`).

I think the problem lies in the implementation of `std::function`, which encapsulates the function pointer and erases the latter's type. (See  [How is std::function implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented)) As a result, a C++ `std::function` is a different type than a plain-C function pointer.

To workaround this, you could relax the C++-ishness a bit and declare `DelayFunction` as accepting `void(*)(unsigned)` instead. I.e., in the C++ file:

```
using LogFunction = std::function<void(const char*)>;
using DelayFunction = std::function<void(unsigned, delay_function_callback_t)>;
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

EDIT: Re. the comment on calling the `DelayFunction` object from C++, instead of passing a lamba function as the callback (which would fail with the workaround above, since the lambda function can only construct a `DelayFunctionCallback`, not a `delay_function_callback_t`), it might be easier to implement the callback as a static member function and use it directly:

```
Utility::getInstance().delay(delay, (delay_function_callback_t)&Utility::next);
```

---

BTW, if `Utility` is going to store the `std::function` objects internally, then it may be more efficient to pass-by-value, since the `LogFunction` and `DelayFunction` objects will always be constructed anyway (i.e. they are rvalue in `core_init`).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that would take away the main reason I'd like to use std::function instead of function pointer. This is how I'd like to use it:

`Utility::getInstance().delay(delay, [this](uint32_t elapsedTime){this->next(elapsedTime);});`

It would not be possible to pass the member function as parameter that way, only if I store the instance in a global variable. Guess I will stick with that solution :/

Comment: @johnyka It seems to me that the problem is you are trying to let C pass a function pointer with a `std::function` argument. My guess is it's not possible just as you can't pass a function pointer in C with an `std::vector` argument?

Comment: Oh damn! Your vector example just made me realize what a dumb thing I'm trying to do :)
Yeah, it makes a perfect sense why it's not possible, for some reason it was harder to imagine with a function within a function.
I think I can accept your answer as a solution if you update it that there's no way to do this exact thing.

Answer (score 1):

A `void(*)()` is fundamentally different from a `std::function<void()>`.

You can get closer with a `void(*)( void* ), void*`; a std function has both callable-ness *and* state, a function pointer only has callable-ness.  (std function also carries RTTI and how-to-cleanup-state and how-to-copy-state).

Now you can convert a `void(*)()` into a std function that is stronger; but not the other way.  And the arguments to a function are converted **the other way** when the call happens.

```
struct callback {
  void* state;
  void(*action)(int32_t);
  void(*cleanup)(void*);
  void*(*copy)(void*);
};
```

that is the rough C equivalent of a `std::function<void(int32_t)>`.