# Casting lambda with non-void return type to function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I am trying to cast a *lambda function* to a *function pointer*. However, the cast fails when the lambda has a non-void return type. Details see the code snippet.

Is it possible to cast `fun2` into a *generic function pointer* which I can save for later usage?

Update: My intention is to cast all kinds of functions to a "generic function pointer" which can be saved in a `std::map`. Upon usage, I will cast it back to its original function type.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int fun3() { return 1; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  typedef void (*voidFunctionType)(void);

  // Case 1: lambda, return type void 
  auto fun1 = []() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; };
  // -> compiles
  auto casted_fun1 = (voidFunctionType)fun1;

  // Case 2: lambda, return type int
  auto fun2 = []() { std::cout << "world" << std::endl; return -1;};
  // -> error: invalid cast from type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda()>’ to type ‘voidFunctionType {aka void (*)()}’
  auto casted_fun2 = (voidFunctionType)fun2;

  // Case 3: free function, return type int -> compiles
  auto casted_fun3 = (voidFunctionType)fun3;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and *trailing-return-type*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you please point out why trailing return type is related here?

Comment: There is none here -- that is why I pointed you to the documentation to learn about it `:)` (it is with the Full-Form of the lambda expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using C-style explicit casts. These are notoriously dangerous.

Here in this case the problem is that `fun3` (in contrast to `fun2`) already decays to a function pointer of type `int(*)()`.

You then cast it to `void(*)()`. This works because the C-style cast will try to do different C++ cast expressions until one works. In particular it will also try a `reinterpret_cast`.

```
reinterpret_cast<voidFunctionType>(fun3)
```

works, because `reinterpret_cast` can cast *any* function pointer to *any* other function pointer.

*However*, you are not allowed to call the function through the obtained pointer. Doing so causes your program to have *undefined behavior*. As you can see this cast is of very limited use and dangerous if you are not aware of it.

Don't use C-style casts, use `static_cast<voidFunctionType>(fun3)` instead and you will get the appropriate compile-time error in both cases.

You cannot use a function (whether free function or lambda) that returns one type as if it returned another (or no) type. Casting the lambda that returns `int` to `void(*)()` therefore doesn't make sense.

---

If you *really* want to save *arbitrary* function pointers you can make the lambda cast work by first converting it to a function pointer and then casting it to the destination function pointer type with a `reinterpret_cast`. I would still not use C style casts, because the `reinterpret_cast` will at least make it clear what kind of cast you are intending to do:

```
auto casted_fun2 = reinterpret_cast<voidFunctionType>(+fun2);
```

The unary `+` is a common trick to force lambda to function pointer conversion. Note however also that only lambdas without capture can be converted to function pointers.

As I explained above though, you *must* cast the pointer back to its original type before calling it, so you need to store the type information somewhere. I am not sure how you intend to do that, but you probably need to implement some extended version of `std::function`, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented) for how `std::function` does it.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889029/6018272) for more about the `+` operator on lambda.