# Should I receive a function by copy, reference or const reference?

Tags: c++11, function-pointers, function-object

When defining a function that takes a function parameter, should I receive a lambda/`std::function` by copy, reference or const reference?

Or all three?

Comment: It also depends on what you're planning on doing with it. Can you tell us more?

Comment: For `std::function`, I would go with copy.

Comment: @Dai I'm considering the case where I'd be implementing functional programming's "map".

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with const ref.  Const because the function shouldn't be changed and ref because then the function taking the parameter doesn't have to check for null.

But don't take my word for it, it will depend case by case.  Here is a duplicate post that provides other perspectives:

[Should I pass an std::function by const-reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365532/should-i-pass-an-stdfunction-by-const-reference)

Comment: Function object that has state?

Comment: Better be careful with functions that captures some values or references.