# passing std::function as parameter with const void *

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following function declaration:

```
void get_data(struct myStruct* const value, const void * const data);
```

I have another function that I want to add a `std::function` as a parameter:

```
// I think the std::function definition is where my problem is
template<typename MyType>
void process(bool test, std::function<void(MyType* const, const void* const)>& callb) { ... }
```

However I can't quite figure out how to call it, or rather if my definition above is correct:

```
bool test1 = true;
process<myStruct>(test1, get_data);
```

Compiler Error:

```
error: prototype for ‘void process(bool, std::function<void(MyType* const, const void* const)>&)’ does not match any in class ‘MyClass’
 void process(bool test,
error: candidate is: template<class MyType> void process(bool, std::function<void(MyType*, const void*)>&)
     void process(bool test,
... goes on
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: @arias_JC, where is the compiler error?

Comment: @arias_JC Please edit your question to include the errors you're getting

Comment: Added compiler error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just have to remove the reference from the function object:

```
void process(bool test, std::function<void(MyType* const, const void* const)> callb);
```

While a reference to a `std::function` object cannot be related to/converted from the underlying function pointer type, the non-referenced object can be implicitely converted to the function pointer type thanks to its constructor.

Edit: Passing `std::function` as const reference gives no performance benefit, but may actually include some penalty in some corner cases, see [Should I pass an std::function by const-reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365532/should-i-pass-an-stdfunction-by-const-reference)

Comment: Making `callb` a const reference [also works](https://ideone.com/dni3P2).

Comment: Ahh so I was removing `&` from cpp file and forgot to remove from header, wow. Thanks this works.

Answer (score 1):

When passing `get_value` to `callb`, the compiler has to construct a temporary `std::function` object for `callb`.  But `callb` is declared as a non-const reference, which cannot be bound to a temporary object.  So make `callb` be a const reference instead, which can be bound to a temporary:

```
template<typename MyType>
void process(bool test, const std::function<void(MyType* const, const void* const)>& callb) { ... }
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/dni3P2)

Comment: this works as well, probably the better solution for my case

Comment: @arias_JC Not necessarily. In either way you end up calling the constructor of std::function, one time for a temporary (in this case) which you access then by const reference or one time for a function-local object. See also my edit.